# Spring boot failing to start with Spring Cloud AWS Core dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I am writing a spring boot app that accesses stuff from an s3 bucket, but I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` when I use the starter `spring-cloud-starter-aws` dependency from the spring initializer.

Am I missing some other dependency here?

Below are my dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I also defined the `dependencyManagement` block for `spring-cloud-dependencies` and use `Edgware.SR1` as my `spring-cloud-version`.

My app fails with the following error when starting up.

```
2018-01-24 12:20:25.642  INFO 1980 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-01-24 12:20:25.666 ERROR 1980 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.art.productattribution.consumerintegration.ConsumerIntegrationApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:616) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

Not sure what am I missing here? Please let me know if you need any more details with this. The version of spring boot I am using is `1.5.9.RELEASE`

Answer (score 1):

The correct dependency is the `spring-cloud-aws-context`. Add the following in your pom file (version 1.2.2 as of Nov 22, 2017):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Below are the Spring Cloud AWS modules:

**Spring Cloud AWS Core** is the core module of Spring Cloud AWS providing basic services for security and configuration setup. Developers will not use this module directly but rather through other modules. The core module provides support for cloud based environment configurations providing direct access to the instance based EC2 metadata and the overall application stack specific CloudFormation metadata.

**Spring Cloud AWS Context** delivers access to the Simple Storage Service via the Spring resource loader abstraction. Moreover developers can send e-mails using the Simple E-Mail Service and the Spring mail abstraction. Further the developers can introduce declarative caching using the Spring caching support and the ElastiCache caching service.

**Spring Cloud AWS JDBC** provides automatic datasource lookup and configuration for the Relational Database Service which can be used with JDBC or any other support data access technology by Spring.

**Spring Cloud AWS Messaging** enables developers to receive and send messages with the Simple Queueing Service for point-to-point communication. Publish-subscribe messaging is supported with the integration of the Simple Notification Service.

Ref: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_using_amazon_web_services

Answer (score 0):

It seems `com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException` is not found in the classpath. I think you can add the following dependency in your POM.xml file to solve this issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But my intent is to use `spring-cloud-starter-aws` 
for autocofigure and get resources from s3. I don't think this change would get the autoconfigure modules. More over, the dependencies that get pulled when I use `Edgware.SR1` is 1.2.2.RELEASE. I guess this is some sort of issue with `spring-cloud-starter-aws`.

Comment: @Wizard AmazonClientException class is not found both in spring-cloud-aws-core and spring-cloud-starter-aws artifacts.

Comment: The class is available in AWS Java SDK.

Comment: I think you can exclude that class from autoconfiguration to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include dependency mentioned by @alltej. Also you need to add below property in application.properties file if you are running on local.

```
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
```